# Proto-Germanic *werthaz: How does 'toward, opposite' imply 'equivalent, worth'?

Tags: etymology

> [worth (adj.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=worth&allowed_in_frame=0) [:]
>   [...] from Proto-Germanic **werthaz* **"toward, opposite,"** hence **"equivalent, worth"** [...]

Please expose and explain the hidden metaphors, notions, and semantic drifts.
How should the etymology be interpreted, to connect  **"toward, opposite,"** with the subsequent **"equivalent, worth"**?

Comment: Well, it is not uncommon for comparisons to metaphorically put the compared objects next to (and possibly facing) each other.

Comment: Considering that this word ended up being used in a trading context (meaning "having value", "this is worth...") however, without having done any research in the topic, my gut-feeling would point more in the direction of it having evolved in phrases equivalent in meaning to "Objekt A gegen Objekt B".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an ***English*** word and its etymologies. It is therefore off-topic on German.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those words have the same etymologic root:

- the German adjective »**wert**« (as in »der *werte* Herr«)
- the German noun »**Wert**« (»der *Wert* des Geldes«)
- the German verb »**werten**« (»Ich möchte sein Verhalten nicht *werten*«)
- the English adjective »**worth**« (»jewelry *worth* $450 was taken«)
- the English noun »**worth**« (»judge a gossips *worth*«)

Also some other Germanic languages have similar words with similar meanings. Old forms are:

Old High German: *werd*
Old Saxonian: *werð*
Old English: *worþ*

There is another interesting word, that is related to the previous, but only exists as a suffix: German **-wärts** and English **-ward(s)** as in:

- vor**wärts** = for**ward(s)**
- rück**wärts** = back**ward(s)**
- ein**wärts** = in**wards**
- aus**wärts** = out**wards**
- ...

Old forms of this suffix are:

Old High German: *-wert*
Old Saxonian: *-ward*
Old English: *-weard*

And there is another common German word, that is related to those words: **werden** (english: to become), with this old forms:

Old High German: *werdan*
Old Saxonian: *werðan*
Old English: *weorþan*

The last word (German *werden*) means: to become something, or to turn into something. So it describes the changing of a thing. Before it had property A, and after*wards* it had property B.

The suffix *-wärts* or *-ward(s)* describes a different place (outwards), a movement into a direction (forward) or a change in time (afterwards). So the common aspect of German *werden* and *-wärts* is changing.

The common protogermanic root »**werthaz**« of all three words (*wert*, *-wärts* and *werden*) also means a transformation, in many different manners. It can mean a movement along a path or the changing of an object when time passes by. It can describe the process of changing (as a verb) as well as its endpoint (as an adjective or noun), and this endpoint can be the opposite of what it was before.

The meaning of *werthaz*, that lead to *wert* and *worth* is the change of quality (from bad to good or reverse). This is the meaning of a verb. It does not only mean, that the object increases it's quality (or gets its quality increased from something else). It can also describe the process of a person who estimates or evaluates an objects quality (without really changing the objects value).

The adjective and the noun describes the property of the endpoint of this changing-process.

Answer (score 0):

Pfeifer’s *Etymologisches Wörterbuch* has [a more extensive presentation (in German)](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=wert) of the possible development. According to him, the word might derive from a root ‘turn’, with an original meaning ‘turned towards something, facing something, opposite to something’. Two things placed side to side could be considered ‘equivalent’; then one thing and an equivalent amount of money (in the widest sense) would indicate how much that thing is worth.

He also points out that Latin *pretium* (of which *price* is derived) may have had a similar development since the etymologically corresponding words in Indian, Greek and Slavic languages are prepositions/adverbs meaning ‘opposite’.

Generally speaking, tracing the development of word meaning in cases like this involves a lot of guesswork. It is often clear that a set of words with widely diverging meaning is etymologically related, but quite unclear how their meanings can be connected. We know from examples that happened in documented stages of the evolution of languages that a word can shift meaning in extreme ways, with many steps in between; for undocumented stages, as in this case, not much can really be said with any degree of certainty.